# Running prettier via eslint vs standalone will result in different outcomes

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

I have configured my eslint to use prettier like this in my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
```

But when I run the command `./node_modules/.bin/prettier -w src/` It reformats three files that `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix` is not changing them or when run without `--fix` it is not nagging about them being wrongly formatted.

One of the differences is that running `prettier` standalone will add an empty line at the end of one file which eslint is not.

Another difference is that running `prettier` standalone will break:

```
    await knex.raw(changeSequenceToRandom({ column: 'id', lowerBound: 1, higherBound: 25 }));
```

to

```
     await knex.raw(
             changeSequenceToRandom({ column: 'id', lowerBound: 1, higherBound: 25 }),
     );
```

in two other files, which eslint is not nagging about them being wrongly formatted again. why is that? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the target file/folder. Try `eslint ./src --fix`.

Comment: Also only running `eslint --fix` do nothing for the project.